# sklearn method model.fit(x---, y--)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a question regarding the model.fit method and overfitting from the scikit learn library in Pandas
Does the generic sklearn method `model.fit(x---, y--)` returns the score after applying the model to the specified training data?

Also, it is overfitting when performance on the test data degrades as more training data is used to learn the model?

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags in your questions

Comment: it is related to machine learning

Comment: Sorry but not directly, also how was it related to `pandas` and `computer-vision`?

Comment: apologies for those two.. also will really appreciate if you can help me understand the two

Answer (score 1):

`model.fit(X, y)` doesn't explicitly give you the score, if you assign a variable to it, it stores all the artifacts, training parameters. You can get the score by using `model.score(X, y)`.

Overfitting in simple words is increasing the variance in your model by which your model fails to generalize. There are ways to reduce overfitting like feature engineering, normalization, regularization, ensemble methods etc.